# Mapping in Hibernate on another field than the PK

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I'm stuck for a moment now and I need some help.

I wanna have a mapping in hibernate between 2 fields that are not PK in any of the both Tables

```
Table Category (
   catId   Numeric(10),
   categoryBusinessRef  Numeric(10)
)


Table Product (
   productId    Numeric(10),
   categoryBusinessRef  Numeric(10)
)
```

The Sql query would be :

```
SELECT * 
   from Category  as a 
   Join Product  as b on a.categoryBusinessRef = b.categoryBusinessRef
```

But in Hibernate it make me this mapping

```
SELECT * 
   from Category  as a 
   Join Product  as b on a.categoryId = b.categoryBusinessRef
```

My hbms looks likes

```
<class name="Category" table="A">
        <id name="categoryId" length="10">
            <column name="categoryid" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">S_category</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <set  name="categoryBusinessRefs" table="B" >
            <key>
                <column name="categoryBusinessRef" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="ProductClass" />
        </set>
</class>

<class name="Product" table="B">
        <id name="productId" length="10">
            <column name="productid" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">S_product</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="categoryBusinessRef" length="10">
            <column name="categoryBusinessRef" />
        </property>
</class>
```

So it's a One-to-many relation but It have to map with another values as the PK of Category

Thanks for the help

EDIT :

If I can't do that ok ! But If I can I want to do that, I know all the stuff with the primary key but my question is not "Mapping in Hibernate on PK" but "Mapping in Hibernate on another field than the PK", so the answers who said map to the PK doesn't interest me :p

Comment: I guess Table `A` is the `1`-side of a OneToMany-Relation, correct? Then, the attribute `disc` in Table `A` is wrong.

Comment: I didn't choose goods names I think, I'll rename those variables

Comment: it's not a matter of good or bad name. Was my assumption correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct but thoses are not unique

Comment: It's more many-to-many indeed

Comment: `one-to-many`  and `many-to-many` are quite different. You have to decide. I must say I'm not familiar with hbms notation, I prefer mapping via annotations in entity java files.

Comment: I can't use Annotations, it's a business requirement :( 
I'm quite fammiliar with all the relations, I use Hibernate for a good time but I can't fix the mapping issue,

Answer (score 1):

Your model is wrong, unless you want to have a cartesian product (it is a rare requirement) you should always join by the primary key.

You can have one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many relationships (the last two are more common).

In one-to-many you need the pk of the `one` side in the `many` side.

In many-to-may you need a relationship table that makes the mapping.

Assuming that you want you want that many `B`'s connect to the same `A` (so one-to-many).

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  id   NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  disc NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE b (
  id    NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id  NUMERIC(10) NOT NUL REFERENCES a (id)
)
```

Now you can query

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
```

and recover all discs from `a` with the proper relation to all `b`.

Comment: Yes but I need to map to other fields because of a Historisations of the database, every update need a new records so there's a Id for the row and an Id for the representation of the data for the business

Comment: But in a lot of case you have to map to certain value that are not primary key (in big data purpose for exemple)

Comment: @GillesBodart The PK must uniquely identify the tuple, so all mapping are done by the PK, you should only apply restriction operations on non-PK fields. Big data not necessarily uses a relational database.

Comment: I know that but my question is not if it's good to do that :) my question is how to do that ;-)

Comment: @GillesBodart And the short answer is you don't do that, all joins must be done by the primary key (which should uniquely identify you relation) unless you want to have a cartesian product. You access the the other fields only after the join is properly done by the PK.

Comment: If I can't do that ok ! But If I can I want to do that, I know all the stuff with the primary key but as I already said my question is not Mapping in Hibernate on PK but "Mapping in Hibernate on another field than the PK", so the answers who said map to the PK doesn't interest me :p

Comment: @GillesBodart Let us know how you made it work without changing your table structure (adding index inclusive).

Comment: I'm not sure at all to be able to do it :)